# While loop only runs once

Tags: bash, scripting

I am writing a simple bash script to check for disk usage on my system. The while loop should only print partitions that are at 85% or above. There are two partitions over 90% but only the first partition is being printed to output.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
admin="foo@bar.com"
threshold="85"

df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1 " " $5}' | sed 's/.$//' | while read i; do
  part=$(echo $i | awk '{print $1}')
  util=$(echo $i | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ $util -ge $threshold ]; then
      echo $part is ${util}% full. An email has been sent to your administrator.
      mail -s "Critical: $part is ${util}% full. Clear space immeadiately!" $admin
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root is 92% full. An email has been sent to your administrator.
```

But, you can see /dev/mapper/rootvg-apps is also 98% full:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-apps            20G   20G  445M  98% /apps
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp            6.0G  2.4G  3.7G  39% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var_log        6.0G   71M  6.0G   2% /var/log
/dev/xvda1                        497M  142M  356M  29% /boot
```

Comment: I suspect your `mail` command reads from stdin and messes up things. (Google for "bash while loop stops after first iteration"). What version/package of mail is that?

Comment: Name:mailx  Arch:x86_64  Version:12.5  Release:12.el7_0   I think you're on to something. When I removed the mail command, both lines were printed. However, the mail component is a crucial part of the script.

Comment: add `echo $i | ` before the mail command. (you might replace $i with a more meaningfull message)

Comment: @Archemar This worked. Can you please help to explain why.

Comment: first output line of df is feeded to `while read` as mail expect value from STDIN it read the rest. my suggest edit provide a STDIN to mail.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your `df -h` output.

Try with `df -Ph`

Update:

As per man page, `-P` refers POSIX output format

```
-P, --portability
    use the POSIX output format
```

And, if your partitions having more length and while doing text processing with your command (without `-P`) your expected line output will be coming in two lines.

Expectation (Example):

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp/tmp1   86
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp/tmp2   90
/tmp   90
```

Actual Output (Example):

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp/tmp1
86
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp/tmp2
90
/tmp   90
```

So, in this case your condition in the script will not match for first two partitions since `'{print $2}'` will be none and `$util -ge $threshold` will be false.

HTH

Comment: I will update my answer with details.